# "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect" when opening file in java

Tags: java, io

I tried inputting quoted and unquoted filenames, but it still only processes up to the first space. Even when there are no spaces in the path, the file's not detected, but the path is correctly displayed. How to fix it?

```
Enter the filename: a b c 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: a (The system cannot find the file specified)
Enter the filename: "a b c "
java.io.FileNotFoundException: "a (The system cannot find the file specified)
```

Is this the best way to get file input?
Also, should I add throws IOException, FileNotFoundException to main or use try{} instead?

```
System.out.print("Enter the filename: ");

Scanner stdin = new Scanner((System.in));  //Keyboard input
String nextDataValue, data, popped="", tag="", fileName=stdin.next();

FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(fis);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(inStream);

data=in.readLine();
```

Comment: You're trying to read a file name that has spaces?

Comment: Use `nextLine()` instead of `next()`, or go with @MДΓΓБДLL's suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scanner is pretty clearly giving you space-delimited tokens. From [the `Scanner` JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

> A `Scanner` breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace.

So there you have it. I hate to say it, but this is a case of RTFD.

Use a different delimiter, or use [`Scanner#nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) instead of [`Scanner#next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29).